# How to use Normalisation groups to get user email only if user equal to the authenticated user

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com

I created a classic `User` class with api-platform and I would like my `GET /users/{id}` endpoint has different behaviour depending on if the authenticated user equal to the `{id}` user.

If I am the same user (show the email)

```
{
  "@context": "/contexts/User",
  "@id": "/users/1",
  "@type": "User",
  "email": "peter@test.com",
  "username": "peter"
}
```

And if not (hide the email)

```
{
  "@context": "/contexts/User",
  "@id": "/users/1",
  "@type": "User",
  "username": "peter"
}
```

I tried to add custom groups on email field like I could read here https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#changing-the-serialization-context-dynamically

But I don't know how to retrieve the information of user object in the `SerializerContextBuilderInterface`

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
 * @Groups({"owner:read", "user:write"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
private $email;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the class that implements SerializerContextBuilderInterface, you can retrieve a current user by passing TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage to constructor. And object `$user` (that needed to serialize) you can get using Request: `$this->userRepository->find($request->get('id'));`
Here the example:

```
public function createFromRequest(Request $request, bool $normalization, array $extractedAttributes = null) : array
{
    $context = $this->decorated->createFromRequest($request, $normalization, $extractedAttributes);

    $route = $request->get('_route');

    if ($route === 'api_users_get_item') {
        $currentUser = $this->token->getToken()->getUser();
        $userToSerialize = $this->userRepository->find($request->get('id'));
        if ($currentUser->getId() === $userToSerialize->getId()) {
            $context['groups'][] = 'owner:read';
        }
    }

    return $context;
}
```